# Do I need to make changes in Bios? I am having an issue upgrading my ram in my Alienware Aurora R4

Tags: memory, ssd, motherboard

I bought 2 Patriot Viper 16GB kits to upgrade to 32GB on my Alienware Aurora R4 and I am getting no video signal no beeps just fans roaring as if it was starting up normal with these installed. But when I take one out and put a corsair 4 GB it boots just fine on 3 Patriot viper 8 GB each and 1 Corsair vengeance 4GB giving me 28 GB of ram.

Alienware Aurora R4
Windows 7 ultimate
3 Samsung 24 inch monitors
Intel i7-4820 CPU @ 3.70Ghz
Nvidia GeForce GTX 680
Motherboard: Alienware 0FPV4P
Max amount of RAM for this computer is 32GB

Ram I am trying to use: Patriot Viper DDR3 Dual channel PC3-12800 1600Mhz 9-9-9-24 UDIMM 8GB per module
Ram I had before the change:Corsair Vengeance DDR3 Dual channel PC3-12800 1600Mhz 9-9-9-24 UDIMM 4GB per module:confused::confused::confused::confused:

Comment: Verify that each module is working by running several iterations of MemTestx86 on each module.  Verify you have restored the UEFI/BIOs default settings.  If you are not running the current firmware, since you have a problem, make sure you upgrade to the current version.

Comment: Yes I have run tests on all modules and all are working properly.

Comment: The bios is also the newest version

Comment: Hardware issue with motherboard can’t be ruled out.  Have you contacted Alienware?

Comment: I have tested all hardware and it is in working order but I might mention my bios is running in legacy mode not UEFI could this be the issue my corsair of the same specs but lower capacity runs perfectly on my Alienware.